# calling methods from run() method in java multithreaded client-server architecutre

Tags: java, multithreading

i am trying to call other methods in run() method. But only when i exit/terminate the client connection the methods are displaying the output.
For example: listall method should print when a client gives listall command. But it gets invoked only when client terminates the connection.

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong here

public void run() {

```
        try {
            System.out.println("Client socket : "+ clientSocket);
            clientPortNumber=clientSocket.getPort();
            clients.add(clientSocket);
            String line;

            while(true) {

                line=is.readLine();
                //System.out.println(line);
                if(line==null)
                    break;
                String temp[]=line.split(" ");

                if(temp[0].equals("ADD")) {
                addRfc();//add method invocation
                }

                else if(temp[0].equals("LOOKUP"))
                send(os);//send method invocation

                else if(temp[0].equals("ListAll")) {
                    listAll(); /*listall method should print when cient gives listall command. But it gets invoked only when client terminates the connection*/
                } else if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))    {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is "is" in is.readLine()? It'd help if you put the whole class for context.

Comment: Where do you expect the `print` to happen and what method are you using to print? System.out.println()?

Comment: If you provide the body of the `listAll()` method, we might be able to give you more specific help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the implementation of the client.  It sounds like the client is buffered and you need to flush the request before the server receive the request.